# How to pass values from different methods in single service file in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a service file, in that I have two methods getdata and delete in that data is coming from API. getdata method is working fine.

I have problem in delete() in that siteId it is not reading any data. If I clicked save button it should identify the siteid and delete that particular data. But I think I have written wrong in service file and component file.

service.ts

```
datasites : Data
getData(): Promise<PagedResult<data>> {

  const url = `${environment.API_URL}/data/GetData`;
  //See that is a "simple" get
  return this.httpClient.get<PagedResult<data>>(url).toPromise();
}
delete(): Promise<Data>{
  alert(2);
  const siteId = this.datasites.principalId;
  const url = `${environment.ADMIN_API_URL}/sites/DeleteSite?siteId=`+ siteId;
  console.log(siteId);
  return this.httpClient.post<Sites>(url, request).toPromise();

}
```

component.ts

```
async ngOnInit(){
      alert("***********");

      this.data = await this.dataService.getData();
      console.log(this.data[0].principalId);
       this.deleteSiteId = this.data[0].principalId;
       console.log(this.deleteSiteId);

    }
   delete(data){
     alert(aaaaaaaaa);
     this.dataService.delete(data);
     console.log(data.principalId);

   }
    showButtons: boolean = false;
  clickEvent(data){
    data.isClicked = !data.isClicked;
  this.showButtons = !data.showButtons;
}
  }
```

.html

```
<div *ngIf="showButtons">
      <button (click)="delete()">Save</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: you have to use this.httpClient.delete method not post method first of all.
second thing why aren't you using observable???

Comment: You need to change `return this.httpClient.delete<Sites>(url, request).toPromise();` and one more thing there is not arguments in delete method in your service which you are sending from your component so change `delete()` to `delete(request)`

Comment: in api they wrote using post only. and i tried with observable also it is not coming

Comment: can you explain why using async on ngOnInit and have you tried using postman

Comment: You will need to pass the data parameter from from front-end html based on the item clicked. You are just calling the delete method with any input parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I can clearly see too many problems with your code.

The glaringly obvious one is that you do not have a linter in whatever editor you are using. If you had that, you would have found the problem. ;)

Aside from that, you are calling the **delete()** method in your ***component.ts*** file without any parameter, which it does want.

You are doing the same thing with the **delete()** in ***service.ts*** file, only in reverse. *Hehe*

It would be extremely useful if you can replicate the above issue in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or any such site.